# lightning:spinner Overlay screen

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

How do I remove the white patch on overlay screen?

```
<div class="slds-align--absolute-center">
        <lightning:spinner aura:id="spinner" variant="brand" size="large" class="slds-hide"/>
     </div>
```

JS:

```
saveNewRecord: function(component) {
        var spinner = component.find('spinner');
        $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, 'slds-show');
    }
```

Issue:
[image]

Comment: i am asuming you have a typo here--> "slds=hide"  or is this actually in your code? Also, any reason you are not using $A.util.toggleClass instead? and why are you using a boolean attribute on your spinner and using aura:if to display it?

Comment: yes, you are right we can use toggle class, I just updated with toggle class, however I am still getting the white patch. am I missing anything else?

Comment: now your css attribute value shows slds-show in your utilit class and in your lightning spinner component slds-hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something like this. better than earlier.

```
.THIS .slds-spinner_container  {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px; 
}
```

Comment: This has no effect for me, the spinner is still shown exactly as in the question.

Comment: `slds-is-relative` is way to go to enclose spinner with its parent container, this feels like a hack.

Answer (score 16):

I recently ran into this issue and the problem is that you need a `slds-is-relative` on the containing element.

When a lightning component is used as part of a quick action SF automatically adds a *bodyWrapper* classed div around the component.

Thus if your component is structured like so:

```
<aura:component>
     <lightning:spinner ....../>
</auraComponent>
```

or

```
<aura:component>
  <div>
     <lightning:spinner ....../>
  </div>
</auraComponent>
```

**The Fix** is to simply add *slds-is-relative* to the containing div, and if there is not one then add one as so

```
<aura:component>
   <div class="slds-is-relative">
     <lightning:spinner ....../>
   </div>
</auraComponent>
```

and the background for the spinner will be contained within the quick action window

Also, since the content is not loaded when the spinner is present you may need to add

```
style="min-height: 50vh;"
```

to the containing div to get the spinner centered.

If we could only get access to the bodyWrapper or if SF would add slds-is-relative to the div they wrap around it we would not need to do the above

Comment: Does not work for me... Or at least this causes the spinner to not act as an overlay anymore. Instead, it pushes all content down. Does that work on your side?

Comment: @WillemMulder I think this fix stopped working and pushed content down starting with summer 18

Comment: Though it solves the problem partially (the big white background is removed), it introduces the new problem, which was also observed by @WillemMulder and confirmed by Eric.

Answer (score 3):

Several pointer from the original code you posted:

> 1- why use a boolean attribute to set the value of your spinner to
>   true or false?
>
> 2.- why wrap the spinner within an `aura:if`?
>
> 3.- I am asuming you had a typo here--> `"slds=hide"`
>
> 4.- why not simply use `$A.util.toggleClass` instead of addClass and RemoveClass?

After updating your post, now you changed the name of the CSS class you are targeting from `slds-hide` to `slds-show` in the `$A.util.toggleClass`. So naturally, this will not work either.

Comment: the toggleClass working fine as expected, only thing which I am not able to figure out is to get rid of the white patch while spinner is ON. by the way with toggle class the code is much simplified. Thank you.

Comment: normally, the overlay should be removed, unless it is not part of the spinner itself. if you to right click and inspect the element, you should be able to fetch the css class value and target it accordingly.

Comment: is this wha you actually have in your code --> $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, 'slds-show'); ??

Answer (score 3):

The following div structure and CSS worked for me when using overlayLib to generate the modal.

In the Lightning Component that you inject into the body of the overlayLib modal, use this div structure with the "slds-is-relative" class applied in the right place.

```
<div>
    <div class="slds-is-relative">
        <aura:if isTrue="{! v.loading }">
            <lightning:spinner size="medium" variant="brand" />
        </aura:if>
        <!-- OTHER MODAL MARK-UP HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in...

[image]

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is still an issue and the solution is just to remove the element *.slds-spinner_container*

Instead of the built-in spinner use this:

```
<div>
<div
  role="status"
  class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_brand slds-spinner_medium"
>
  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
  <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
</div>
```

And you will get the desired result

[image]

Comment: This answer is the best answer because it removes the slds-spinner_container class that is causing the problem with the OOTB spinner.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code in .css file of lightning component, working for any height

```
.THIS.slds-spinner_container{
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the best solution to this annoying issue is to use wrapper `div` which will be `relative` around lightning `spinner` element. Simply put `slds-is-relative` class on the `div` and voila.

Here is example:

```
<div class="slds-is-relative">
   <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading..." size="small" />
</div>
```

Comment: Also works around a section of your component. E.g. the datatable hidden until the data is loaded:
          <div style="height: 300px;" class="slds-is-relative">
                <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" alternativeText="Loading"/>
                
                <lightning:datatable
                                     keyField="id"
                                     data="{!v.tableData}"
                                     columns="{!v.tableColumns}">
                </lightning:datatable>
            </div>

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue and this is how I fixed this.

```
<div style="min-height:3rem;transform: translate(0, 0);">
    <lightning:spinner size="medium" alternative-text="Loading"></lightning:spinner>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The white patch is due to the div wrapping the spinner element which has the class applied

> slds-align--absolute-center

Please change the class or take out the div.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your custom modal header, body or footer component:

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container {
        position: absolute;
        height: fit-content;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
</aura:html>
```